# Convergence of Sequences simple

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_{2n}$,$x_{2n+1}$,$x_{3n}$ converge.Show that $x_{n}$ converges.

One idea was saying that the sequences cover all the numbers and they all converge to x.Hence $x_{n}$ converges to x. I wanted an explicit solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Any natural number $n$ can be odd or even. So $x_n$ can be represented by $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$. Can you complete it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

$$\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=A\\{}\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+1}=B\end{cases}$$

Observe that $\;\{x_{3n}\}\;$ is a subsequence of **both** $\;\{x_{2n}\}\;,\;\;\{x_{2n+1}\}\;$ , and thus

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{3n}=C=A=B\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

and thus all the limits are equal.

Now you just need the following:

Lemma: Suppose $\;X,Y\;$ are disjoint subsets of $\;\Bbb N\;$ and also $\;X\cup Y=\Bbb N\;$ ,  such that for some sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ we have that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty\,,\,\,n\in X}a_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty\,,\,\,n\in Y}a_{n}=T$$

Then also $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=T\;$

The above lemma can be generalized to a finite number of pairwise disjoint subsets of the naturals .